# How to change date formating to yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: development, date-time

I have got this code:

```
dzienStart = Convert.ToDateTime(properties.AfterProperties["DzienStart"]).ToLocalTime().AddHours(-1.0);
dzienStart = Convert.ToDateTime(dzienStart.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
dzienStop = Convert.ToDateTime(properties.AfterProperties["DzienStop"]).ToLocalTime().AddHours(-1.0);
dzienStop = Convert.ToDateTime(dzienStop.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

But it's not changing the date format. I still have got the date in format ***7/30/2015***. Please help.

Comment: This won't change the date format because System.DateTime will always use the local system format. You are actually converting your System.Datetime variable to yyyy-MM-dd string but when you convert this to System.Datetime again, it converts the string to your system format. Change your PC's calendar settings to yyyy-MM-dd and check this. It will convert it.

Comment: Yes I know, but how to change to my format ?

Comment: Change your PC settings.

Comment: OnPC calendar setings on serwer i have got 2015-08-03 so good format.

Comment: But on server is 2015-08-03

Comment: Oh OK. I just changed my PC settings to match yours and I got DateTime.Now as {2015-08-03 3:06:03 PM}. What do you get? I think you'll get the same format if it is in yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: Im. geting it on my servertest PC where I programing solution for sharepoint. And in my computer too.

Comment: I can't change it by progrability ?

Comment: Since `AfterProperties` needs an ISO8601 format, you can try to create like this: `Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(DateTime.Now);` Shamelessly taken from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/anjali_chelawat/archive/2009/06/16/how-to-modify-a-datetime-value-in-sharepoint-afterproperties.aspx

Comment: For why it is converting to 7/30/2015, my best guess is your SharePoint regional settings are in US format.

Comment: But how to change them

Comment: And globaly change them for all users.

Comment: I change a regional seting in Site Collection, and in list it works. Now I must try a lot of tests :)

Comment: This also works for me. `string s = Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTim‌​e(DateTime.Now);DateTime d2 = DateTime.Parse(s, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);`

Comment: The question is it will work with AfterPropeties to ?

Comment: And what is mean RoundtripKind

Comment: Scrap that. I was testing with the yyyy-mm-dd system time. Changing timezone showed the datetime in different timezone format. So I guess you'll have to change regional settings of SharePoint to change format.

Comment: Yes I change this for Polish. And it worked.

Answer (score 2):

A Workaround for the missing ISO date format may be to set the regional setting to "English (South Africa)". The the dates will by shown as yyyy/mm/dd, which is already nearly the ISO format. Microsoft should add an additional locale to the predefined list!